# Hash functions in R: keys and values as doubles?

Tags: r, hash

I'm fairly new to R.  I want to use a hash function to hold key-value pairs as doubles/numerics.

I have a function `f(x) = y` where the function `f` takes the input `x` as a double and returns `y` as a double.  I use this function `f(x)` over 10^8 times in my code (and I would like to use it much more often), and 99% of the time `f(x)` has been computed once already.  I would like to store my answers as key-value pairs, so I can find them instead of calculating them again.

I read the article below about using environments as hash tables, but I cannot figure out how to use doubles as key-value pairs.
https://www.r-bloggers.com/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-i/

How do I use doubles as key-value pairs in a hash function in R?

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking to do has already been solved by the [memoise package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/index.html). Maybe just start there.

Comment: Taking a look at the memoise package...